# Tickets for occasional public transport use in Lille?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, france, lille

I'm trying to work out what the best ticketing option will be for occasional uses of public transport in Lille. Say, 3-4 trips a week for several weeks, mostly within the centre of the city, mixture of buses and metro.

I know that in some cities (eg [London](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/2043/26) or [Brisbane](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11239/when-visiting-brisbane-how-can-you-work-out-if-you-should-get-a-gocard-or-the)) you can get a card which you load with money, then use on a pay-as-you-go basis as you travel. I know that other cities (eg [Hong Kong](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11239/when-visiting-brisbane-how-can-you-work-out-if-you-should-get-a-gocard-or-the)) you can get a card you load with money that works for both public transport and small purchases. There are some cities where you can buy either a multi-use ticket or a booklet of single tickets at a discount, which can be used over time. There are some cities which sadly offer no sort of discount for occasional use.

So, for Lille, what's the best / available ticket option, for occasional public transport use?

Answer (score 3):

In Lille, the trip count paradigm is used.

According to this : [Transpole](http://www.transpole.fr/fr/pass-pass-et-tarifs/titres-occasionnels.aspx)

- Single trip €1.50
- 10 trips €12.50
- Short trip €0.80 (3 stops max, on subway and light rail only)
- Day pass €4
- 2-day pass €7.50
- 3-day pass €9.50
- After 7pm evening pass €2

All fares allow transfers. Single trip and each trip out of the 10-trip package do not allow returns on the same trip.

Note : Lille has switched to contactless tickets even for single trips. There is a €0.20 fee for getting the ticket in addition to the fare; the ticket can then be reloaded 9 times with the same type of fare only; the €0.20 are credited back at the 5th reloading. One reloading is counted each time a single purchase process is completed at the machine, even if several tickets are bought during the purchase process.

You can also get a contactless smart card for €2 and load it the same way.

Special "Braderie" weekend pass €5 (if it is for the "braderie" that takes place in September)